# Reproducing "multiple declarations" error from linker

Tags: c++, linker, g++, linker-errors, multiple-definition-error

So, I was going to demonstrate the problem of (non-template) implementation in C++ .h files to a college.

But right now I can't reproduce it as expected. Here's my code:

```
// common.h

#ifndef common_h
#define common_h

#include <iostream>

class common
{
    public:
    void Hello() {
        // Implementation in header file
        std::cout << "Hello from common" << std::endl;
    }
};

#endif // common_h
```

```
// user1.h

#ifndef user1_h
#define user1_h

#include "common.h"

class user1
{
    public:
    user1();
    
    private:
    common g;
};

#endif // user1_h
```

```
// user1.cpp

#include "user1.h"

#include <iostream>

user1::user1()
{
    std::cout << "Constructing user 1" << std::endl;
    g.Hello();
}
```

```
// user2.h

// Exactly as user1.h except the class+constructor name
```

```
// user2.cpp

// Exactly as user1.cpp except the class+constructor name
```

```
// main.cpp

#include "user1.h"
#include "user2.h"

int main()
{
    user1 u1;
    user2 u2;
}
```

I'm compiling the code like this:

```
g++ -c -g -O0 -fno-lto -fno-inline-small-functions user1.cpp
g++ -c -g -O0 -fno-lto -fno-inline-small-functions user2.cpp
g++ -c -g -O0 -fno-lto -fno-inline-small-functions main.cpp

g++ user1.o user2.o main.o
```

Nothing fails and program works as expected.

Why am I not getting a "multiple declarations" error on the "Hello" function in common.h?

I looked into the object files (using objdump) and I see this tag: LINK_ONCE_DISCARD. Could this be the reason? Can anyone supply more details? I'm sure I've seen this before so something must have change (maybe from a compiler update or something).

Compiler version:

```
>g++ --version
g++ (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: A function defined inside the class declaration is automatically `inline`, so the linker takes care of removing duplicates.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea.  Defining Hello outside (but still in the header file) gives me the expected error. Thank you, @BoP

Comment: @DoP, do you really mean "inline" in the sense that the code will be inlined in a caller and not result in a call to "Hello"?

Comment: @jgreen81 Yes, although you should remember inline is only a "recommendation" to the compiler (i.e. it can be ignored anyway).

Comment: The [inline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) keyword has two meanings - that a function might be expanded inline, and that it can be included several times without creating a duplicate. The second part is the most important nowadays. Modern compilers will tend to expand functions where it makes sense, whether they are marked or not - that's why you need `-fno-inline-small-functions` to ask it not to...

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of "inline variables" but not that this effect also affected functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BoP, here's the answer:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

My "Hello" function is inline because it is defined inside a class declaration.